# Error Installing LetsEncrypt SSL Cert on Forge Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, lets-encrypt, laravel-forge

I'm trying to install a LetsEncrypt cert on a Forge load balancer and continually receive the `ERROR: Challenge is invalid!` error message.

My DNS is all good; I was successful in installing certs on a couple other servers using subdomains of the domain I'm trying now.

My best guess is that the challenge is being generated on the load balancer, but the check is being routed to my balanced servers, instead of on the load balancer itself, so it will always fail.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it to work so just purchased one from RapidSSL.